# How to run a bash file that does not exited when my program ends python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a python program which is instantier as a linux service.
This service updates itself by downloading a new version of the code on an ftp server and launches a bash file to update the service.
In this file I have a line that destroys the current service before recreating it with the new source code.
I run this bash script with:

```
subprocess.call("sudo bash /home/pi/install.sh",shell=True)
```

I understand that this "subprocess" lives in my python program. And the bash script stop the linux service so stop the python program so stop itself ... And so it never ends.

What are the solutions to solve my problem?

Comment: What is the question/issue exactly?

Comment: How can I call a bash script from a python program which does not terminate if the python program terminates

Comment: How about sudo bash -c nohup /home/pi/install.sh &"

Comment: I'm getting nohup : missing operand

Comment: What do you mean by "is instantier as a linux service"? Is it managed by some OS facility (e.g. systemd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's several ways to do it - one of them being (maybe not the most elegant?) to make your python schedule a cron-job of the bash-script using [python-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/).

Say it's 13:00 and you want your job to run - then make the python script schedule a cron-job to 13:05 (just to add a time buffer).
You can then remove your cron-job after the bash-job has been run, either manually or implement it in your bash-script (or make it call a python script which uses [python-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) to remove it, it's fairly easy to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the script stop the service. Just let it exit with a specific exit code if it installed a new version, and restart the service accordingly in the Python code.